# In Yii, is there a way to write the schema in something like YAML or XML?

Tags: mysql, schema, yaml, yii

I've been using Symfony in which you write the schema in YAML, and I'm surprised that in both Kohana and Yii I have to write the schema in SQL.

For me, the advantages of having it in YAML are that it offers default values, a database-neutral schema, better readability, and... well it's just easier than writing the MySQL myself.

So, 2 questions:

1. Is there an advantage to writing the SQL myself?
2. Is there a way of writing a YAML schema in Yii?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yii has been written pretty well.  It works with third party libraries.  Here is the link on how to use a [third party library](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/extension.integration).

Also, you don't have to write SQL in Yii.  You can use active record.  Like:

```
$model= new TableModel();
$model->attributes=$_POST['form'];
$model->save();
```

This will write an insert query for the table you modeled with [Active Record](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar).

Comment: Are there pros and cons either way?

Comment: I personally like active record.  I don't have to write SQL for simple crud tasks.  This makes for a quick development environment.  If you have an extremely complex query you can still dip down to that level with the active record class and write SQL.

Comment: Yii now has a "query builder" as well: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder

Answer (score 0):

Yii also has a Migration tool since 1.1.6 :
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.migration

You could then define your schema in non SQL + having the benefit of versioning + migrating up/down your DB.

Comment: Hm, that's interesting - I've seen migration work well in Rails. I will check this out, thanks.